# How can we check if a given input is a valid system command like "ls" or "cd" in c program?

Tags: c, bash

I am writing a c program that takes system commands such as "ls" or "cd" as inputs.However user can give any type of commands out of which some are not commands.How can i find which command is valid and which is not?I am writing the code in Ubuntu.

Comment: of course you would pick ls and cd which are two very different beasts. Generally you can find it out only by trying to run it in shell.

Comment: Are you writing a shell by any chance?

Comment: The normal technique is to try running the command — if it works, it was valid; if it can't be found, it wasn't valid.  A shell has to deal with built-in commands (such as `cd`) specially.  It might also have functions or aliases to use.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler running shell commands that the user gives you without any prior validation is a highway to Command Injection...

Comment: Standard shells don't do anything different, @JeffUK.  I have hundreds of scripts which no shell knows about, but all the shells run those scripts without problems because they are on my path and executable.  I gave lots of binaries too that no shell knows about; they too run fine because they are on my path and executable.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head there are two ways to check if the input is a valid system command, *without* actually attempting to run it:

1. A long list of `if()`s and `else if()`s which `strcmp()` the input string with a hard-coded, predetermined list of valid commands - this may be relatively slow, both to write and to run, but with conditional-compilation with `#ifdef`, can be nearly perfectly portable (i.e, can be made to work with Windows, Linux, BSD *et all* from one codebase with enough hard work).
2. If you don't mind being restricted to a UNIX-like platform only, parse the `$PATH` variable, and search for executables with the same filename as the input string in the directories found from `$PATH`, and handle errors if no match is met.

You may wish to implement a *hybrid* of `2.` and `1.` by hard-coding some exceptions which may not be found in `$PATH`.

IMHO, however, I fail to see why you would want to do this; it seems puzzling to me.

Comment: you can't find cd in path.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala aha, good point. Well, then is it set somewhere in some file ?

Comment: There's no standard ?

Comment: there is a posix standard and there are commands that are not in standard

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Well, obviously there is not going to be a perfect catch-all unless *hard-coded* , so maybe a hybrid of the two would work well.

Comment: Note that on Linux (and macOS X, and probably other POSIX-based systems too), there is an external utility (in POSIX-speak) `/usr/bin/cd`.  Invoking it doesn't do much good — specifically, it doesn't change the current shell's directory — but it exists.

Comment: So, per Jonathan's comment, @AnttiHaapala , `cd` **does** indeed exist in `$PATH` , since `/usr/bin` would certainly be included in `$PATH`

Comment: See the [Introduction](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html) to POSIX "Shell & Utilities" and §1.6 Built-in Utilities. It says: _"However, all of the standard utilities, including the regular built-ins in the table … shall be implemented in a manner so that they can be accessed via the exec family of functions …"_ See also [Regular Built-In Utilities](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tagtcjh_18) and [Special Built-In Utilities](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14).

Comment: Indeed , I use MacOS 10.14.6 and I can verify that this is true. However, on my Ubuntu system , I get the same outcome as Anitti

Comment: `cd` is actually explained well here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50058/16777 - it does make some pervert sense. But it is not in GNU coreutils for some reason.